# Does a non space breaker exist in html css?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, frontend, ascii

I would like to get this element wrap to any of the slash characters:

```
<p>iOS/WEB/Other/Installation/Backend/AR</p>
```

As you can see there is no spaces and I don't want to use word-wrap in the css because that could give something like this:

```
iOS/WEB/Other/Insta
llation/Backend/AR
```

Is there a charactere such as \n or \r that I could add to my string that fulfilled the requirement.
A breakpoint but that doesn't display any character.

Actually using \n and \r put spaces between the words and I really don't want spaces.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the `U+FEFF ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE` ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Indeed ;) `U+200B ZERO WIDTH SPACE`